# How to find mean of a plot generated by Manipulate?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I have a plot that I'm manipulating:

```
Manipulate[Plot[PDF[GammaDistribution[alpha, beta], x], {x, 0, 5}], {alpha, 1, 5}, {beta, 1, 5}]
```

I want to manipulate it until it meets some characteristic, say, `Mean` is some particular value. How can I see the `Mean` of a plot that I'm manipulating?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Manipulate[
 mean = Mean@GammaDistribution[alpha, beta];
 color = If[Abs[mean - controlMean] <= 0.01, Red, Blue];
 Show[{
   Plot[PDF[GammaDistribution[alpha, beta], x], {x, 0, 5}, 
    PlotStyle -> color, PlotRange -> All],
   Graphics[{color, Line[{{0, mean}, {5, mean}}], Dashed, Red, 
     Line[{{0, controlMean}, {5, controlMean}}]}]
   }],
 {{controlMean, 3}, 1, 5}, {alpha, 1, 5}, {beta, 1, 5}]
```

Here controlMean is the value of the mean of the distribution that you want to achieve. You can vary it with the slider. Its level is shown by the dashed red line. The solid blue line shows the actual mean value. As soon as you arrive closer than 0.01 to this value the whole plot turns into the red:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Ooooo, so fancy.  ;-) The mean and controlMean are of course, on the wrong axis, so I went ahead and changed that, but I don't know how to allow the Y axis to auto-scale... Here's my mod: `Manipulate[mean = Mean@GammaDistribution[alpha, beta];
 color = If[Abs[mean - controlMean] <= 0.01, Red, Blue];
 Show[{Plot[PDF[GammaDistribution[alpha, beta], x], {x, 0, 500}, 
    PlotStyle -> color, PlotRange -> All], 
   Graphics[{color, Line[{{mean, 0}, {mean, 1}}], Dashed, Red, 
     Line[{{controlMean, 0}, {controlMean, 1}}]}]}], {{controlMean, 
   300}, 1, 500}, {alpha, 1, 5}, {beta, 1, 500}]`

Comment: To make it scalable remove the option `PlotRange...` from the code. Besides, regarding the values of the mean I propose to replace the conditional operator with something like the following: `color = If[Abs[mean - controlMean] <= controlMean/200, Red, Blue];`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

dist = GammaDistribution[alpha, beta];

Mean[dist]

(* alpha beta *)
```

So for a fixed mean, `beta = mean/alpha`

```
Quantile[dist, 99/100]

(* beta InverseGammaRegularized[alpha, 0, 99/100] *)

Manipulate[Module[{mode, modeVal},
  dist = GammaDistribution[alpha, mean/alpha];
  mode = ArgMax[PDF[dist, x], x] // Quiet;
  modeVal = Limit[PDF[dist, x], x -> mode,
     Direction -> "FromAbove"] // N;
  Show[
   Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, 0, mean/alpha*InverseGammaRegularized[alpha, 
          0, 99/100]}, 
    PlotLabel -> 
     StringForm["PDF[GammaDistribution[`1`,`2`], x]", alpha, mean/alpha],
    Epilog -> {Red, Dashed,
      Line[{{mean, 0}, {mean, PDF[dist, mean]}}]},
    PlotRangePadding -> {0.01, {0.01, 0.1 modeVal}}],
   ListPlot[{Callout[{mode, modeVal}]}]]],
 {{alpha, 2}, 1, 5, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{mean, 2}, 1, 15, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]